# How does one prove that the conservative force $\vec{F}$ is equal to the negative gradient of the potential $V$?

Tags: forces, potential-energy, definition, differentiation, integration

I have a grasp of the gradient theorem, and I understand that if we let $\phi$ be a function such that $\vec{F}=\nabla \phi$, and $V(\vec{x})$ be the potential at $\vec{x}$, then

$$-\int _C\vec{F}d\vec{x} = \phi (p)-\phi (q) = V(p)-V(q)$$

where $C$ is a path which starts at $p$ and ends at $q$. I've seen some proofs (take, for example, the second proof in [this post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-the-conservative-force-is-the-negative-gradient-of-potential-energy-i-e-F-grad-U)) that, from the latter equation, jump straight to $\phi = V$. If this step is valid, I do not understand why.

Comment: I'd appreciate if those who downvote could explain why, so that I can improve the post accordingly.

Comment: How are you defining $\phi$ and $V$ here?

Comment: @BySymmetry I edited the question. Let me know if more clarification is needed.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you don't take Quora as an authoritative reference. That answer uses the term "conservative" twice in the same answer and uses it incorrectly in the beginning  "if a force acting on an object is a function of position only, it is said to be a conservative force, and it can be represented by a potential energy function..."

From the equation you have, it does NOT follow $\phi=V$, rather, $\phi$ and $V$ differ by a constant. More explicitly, suppose we're working inside some region $\Omega$ (more precisely a connected open set in say $\Bbb{R}^3$) and we fix a point $p\in \Omega$. Then, for each $x\in \Omega$, we let $C_{p,x}$ denote a ($C^1$) path from $p$ to $x$. Then, we have (supposing $\mathbf{F}=-\nabla \phi=-\nabla V$)
\begin{align}
-\int_{C_{p,x}}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{l}=\phi(x)-\phi(p)=V(x)-V(p)
\end{align}
or rearranging, $\phi(x)-V(x)=\phi(p)-V(p)$. Since this equation holds for all $x\in\Omega$, we have thus shown that the difference $\phi(\cdot)-V(\cdot)$ is the constant function whose value is the number $\phi(p)-V(p)$.

This should make sense to you because specifying (a conservative) force $F$ is like specifying the derivative of a function, and this function is obtained by integration. But of course, we can add any constant and still the new thing will be such that when differentiated, we recover our original force $F$ (so what I've written above is an immediate generalization of the fact in single-variable calculus that if $f,g:(a,b)\to\Bbb{R}$ are differentiable functions such that $f'=g'$, then it follows that the difference $f-g$ is a constant function).